# Trying to create number guessing game. SyntaxError: Bad Input

Tags: python

I've just started programming on python, and I'm trying to make a really basic number guessing game. Apparently I've made a really obvious mistake. I'd be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction!

-Cheers

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaIDH.png

Comment: Just a missing `)`.

Comment: Post your code here, not screenshots..

Comment: `int(input())`  You must close the int **and** input

Answer (score 0):

- Line 4 is missing a `)` at the end
- Line 5 has extra `_` at the end (unless it is your blinking cursor)
- Line 10 is not indented enough (needs to go one tab to the right)
- You should use the same indentation throughout your script (eg. four spaces)

Also, you should always copy the code here instead of posting screenshots - it is much harder for people to try your code this way.

Comment: line 5 might just be his blinking cursor.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Sorry about wasting your time with my stupid mistakes :^)

Comment: @StevenEdward03: No worries, we were all beginners once. If it helped, you should consider upvoting the answer and accepting it.